# How can I set popover title bar color to the same as default navigationBar?

Tags: ipad, uikit, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller, uicolor

I have some buttons on popover title bar, they are in dark color, so that I want to the popover title bar color can be changed to the same as Navigation Bar color, what can I do? You will see the gray title bar in popover, how can I do it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what your code looks like, but from the screen shots I assume that you are presenting a UINavigationController as the content of the UIPopoverController. If that is the case you'll need to set the tintColor or barStyle property on the navigationBar property of the UINavigationController.

If this poses problems you may have to nest the UINavigationController within another view (crazy I know) If its nested within a white view, it should use the default style of the UINavigationBar.